# Is there a performance decrease from not specifying the this word in a AS3 file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I know there are performance loses if you don't specify variable types explicitly. Do ActionScript/Java developer in general prefer the use of the in classes or no?

```
public function hello():void
{
   this.speaker.says("hello");
}
```

vs

```
speaker.says("hello")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the shorter form, there are no performance differences and the shorter form is generally preferred.

Comment: only use "this" when there are method-parameters that match the name of a local class attribute. 
     public function(test1:String) { this.test1 = test1;}

Comment: Is this preference documented anywhere? I always write "this" because it's clearer to me what's going on, but I never got that habit from any specific code guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

There is no performance difference, it's just down to a matter of personal preference.

I prefer to use this.foo, personally.  I sense I'm in the minority.

Comment: +1 i am with you on this one. The this helps define scope of the var and to me over all looks better. I actually feel it horrid programming when I see free libraries posted that do not use "this".

Answer (score 1):

The only time it's really useful to use `this` in AS3 could be, for example in a constructor where there may be some ambiguity between the method params and the instance params:

```
private var foo:String;
private var bar:String;

myClass( foo:String, bar:String ) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
}
```

But there is an issue of whether that is good programming style anyway.